# Could not determine recommended JdbcType, Springboot 3 + Hibernate 6

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-6.x

After migration my Springboot project from 2.7X to 3.1 i'm getting

```
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.JdbcTypeRecommendationException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType
```

My setup:
I have postgress views and using native queries where result is mapped to java object via @SqlResultSetMapping

Here is my test code

```
package de.test.hibernate.resutlmapping.Resutlmapping;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.java.Log;

@SpringBootApplication
@Log
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "de.test.hibernate.resutlmapping" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "de.test.hibernate.resutlmapping" })

public class ResutlmappingApplication {

    @Autowired
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void deleteMe() {
        var select2 = "SELECT a.key as key FROM public.configurations a";
        Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(select2, TestClass2.class);
        List<Object[]> result = nativeQuery.getResultList();
        log.info("" + result.size());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResutlmappingApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
package de.test.hibernate.resutlmapping.Resutlmapping;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "TestClass2Mapping", classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = TestClass2.class, columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "key", type = String.class)
                }) })
public class TestClass2 {

    private String key;
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <!-- <version>2.7.15</version> -->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.test.hibernate.resutlmapping</groupId>
    <artifactId>Resutlmapping</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Resutlmapping</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thank you so much for any advice.

I also tried to call native query as

```
Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(select2, "TestClass2Mapping");
```

then it throws
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not resolve specified result-set mapping name : TestClass2Mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution
@SqlResultSetMapping class has to be also antotated with @Embeddable
and then native sql query call like

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(select2, "TestClass2Mapping");
```

is working.